# Expo React Native Cannot find module './assets/empty-module.js'

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I create new project with

`expo init AwesomeProject`

after run `npm start`. But I have error

```
Error: Cannot find module './assets/empty-module.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.require.resolve (internal/module.js:23:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH/TO/MY/PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:20:29)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at loader (/PATH/TO/MY/PROJECT\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/PATH/TO/MY/PROJECT\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `root` project folder and run:

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn
```

Work for me.